# Prove that this equation have an non finite number of prime solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So the question seeks to answer the following, let $x,y\in\Bbb R$. Prove that there is a non finite number of prime solutions to the following equation: $3x-5y=11$. Our professor says that it's easy but I don't see how!

Comment: I don't even understand the question. Solutions are ordered pairs $(x,y)$. What does it mean for such an ordered pair to be prime?

Comment: @GitGud I guess it means that both x and y are prime

Comment: If "prime solutions" means what Stefano thinks, was it perhaps the task to show that there are only finitely many prime solutions?

Comment: Perhaps he meant "relatively prime".

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to $3x-5y=11$ is $x=7+5t,\ y=2+3t.$ Note that then $x-y=5+2t$ is odd, so that for any $t$ one of $x,y$ is even. So once they both exceed $2$ they cannot both be primes. [It seems if one allows negative $x,y,t$ the only initially doubtful case is $t=-1$ for which $x=2,y=-1,$ but since $-1$ is not a prime this doesn't count.]

Edit: As Daniel Fisher points out in his comment the $t=0$ case is $x=7,y=2$ with both primes. But I think this is the only one, even allowing negative primes, since at $t\le -2$ we have $x\le -3,y\le -4$ with one of them even.

Comment: There is one solution where both are primes, $3\cdot 7 - 5\cdot 2 = 11$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I included that just now (and mentioned your comment).

Comment: You forgot a 'c' in my name, however. More to the point, yes, that is the only solution with $x$ and $y$ both prime. We must have $x \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ and $y\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, and as you said, one must be even. Since $-2$ doesn't satisfy the congruences, we must have $x = 2$ or $y = 2$. Since $-1$ isn't prime, $(7,2)$ is the only solution with both prime.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the Euclide algorithm to find one solution. For example, $x = 2\times 11$ and $y = 1\times 11$.
2. Now, substract the equation and the solution:
   $$
   0 = 11 - 11 = 3x - 5y - (3\times22 - 5\times 11) = 3(x -11) - 5(y-11)
   $$
   and use Gauss theorem.